# scontents – environment content does not show up

Tags: environments

I am trying the interesting [scontents](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/scontents/scontents.pdf) package.

I am quickly facing issues like the environment content is not displayed while I set that key to `print-env=true`.

Where am I wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{scontents}[print-env=true, write-out=TestFile,overwrite=true]

Something for main A.

\end{scontents}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Feels like a package bug to me, the documentation says nothing about it. As workaround you can obviously do a `getstored` afterwards

Comment: It is documented and with the word NOT in capital letters :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `write-env` not `write-out`. That will also store the content so that it can be printed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{scontents}[print-env=true, write-env=TestFile,overwrite=true]
Something for main A.

\end{scontents}

\end{document}
```

Comment: my bad ! thank you.